# Java: Is it safe to import from jdk.*?

Tags: java, nashorn

Is it safe for me to write a Java program with imports like this:

```
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory;
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ClassFilter;
```

Note: 
**In my example I import Nashorn, but it could be any other jdk package.**

Note: I know that it's safe/correct to import from java.* , javax.* and unsafe/unsupported to import from sun.*

I saw a good article here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html

I can't find anywhere in the Java official documentation that tells me one way or another

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are supposed to use them through `javax.script` as explained on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/package-summary.html

> ## Package jdk.nashorn.api.scripting Description
>
> This package provides the `javax.script` integration, which is the preferred way to use Nashorn. You will ordinarily do this to obtain an instance of a Nashorn script engine:

```
import javax.script.*;
...
ScriptEngine nashornEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("Nashorn");
```

---

But to answer your question, i would say "Probably not". The only officially guaranteed supported packages are `java.*`,`javax.*`, and `org.*`.

Since those are the only supported packages, it follows that **all** other packages are not supported.

Any new unsupported packages would not be named `sun.*` since Oracle now owns Java.

It's likely that someone picked `jdk.*` as a new unsupported package prefix since `sun.*` is no longer available.

That said, it's somewhat unlikely that they will remove it any time soon, unless they decide to replace it for another Javascript engine, like they already did before.

The other potential problem is that your program won't run on another JDK that does not include Nashorn.

Comment: Another explicit occurence is the Java9 Migration guide from Oracle. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-F7696E02-A1FB-4D5A-B1F2-89E7007D4096

Comment: My question: is generic. Is it safe to import from jdk.* ? 
Obviously I want to access the classes directly because of extra features. I will update the text of my question. thanks

Comment: I updated the answer. The only explicitly supported packages are `java.*`, `javax.*`, and `org.*`. That means `jdk.*` is not explicitly supported.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Thanks. But you still have not found anywhere in the JDK docs that says refrain from using "jdk.*". The thing is that in some cases people are told to use directly the NashornScriptEngine hence importing it as is...

Comment: @Zo72: They're using a whitelist, not a blacklist. They're not saying that any package that is not `sun.*` is supported, they're saying that any package that is not `java.*`, `javax.*` or `org.*` is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

jdk.nashorn.api.* packages are nashorn script engine specific APIs (whereas javax.script is scripting language independent API). If you're using nashorn in your code and you want nashorn specific access (like accessing script object from Java code reflectively - using jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror), then you can use these APIs. If you want to keep your java code independent of specific scripting language implementation, then you may want to stick to javax.script.

javadoc for nashorn APIs is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/